# Using Angular UI-Grid, how do you access row entity data without using the row selection?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to switch from **Smart-Table** version 1.x to Angular **ui-grid** (version 3.0), the replacement for *ng-grid*.
I like nearly everything about *ui-grid*, but one thing is driving me crazy.  In *smart-table*, there is a value for `dataRow`, which is a convenient way of referencing the entity within a table.

What I was using it for was populating an html template to include field information from the entity, something like `ng-click="$parentScope.edit(dataRow.id)"` within the html template placed within a grid cell.

However, in *ui-grid*, I can't seem to access the entity object without making a formal row or cell selection.  Any effort to include it in a cell template results in an object, (`row.entity`) but I cannot access any of the entity elements, they show up as undefined. Any ideas?

Furthermore, I have been able to execute a method in an html template, but only ones with no parameters, not one trying to use a parameter from the entity itself.

Here is my html template that was working with *smart-table*:

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View    {{filteredRowCollection}}"   ng-click="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.view(dataRow.id)"
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera green">
</a>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit {{selectionId}}" ng-click="grid.appScope.edit(row.entity.id)"
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil blue">
</a>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete {{selectionId}}"  ng-click="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.delete(dataRow.id)"
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash red">
</a>
```

I was trying to use something like this with *ui-grid*:

```
function edit(row){
    . . .
};
```

`row`, at this point is an object, as is `row.entity`. I expected to be able to use something like `row.entity.id`, one of the fields, but it is `undefined`.

Comment: Small error in my cut and paste.  The ng-click line for the edit was actually one of my tests.  What is should read is ng-click="grid.appScope.edit(row.entity.id)"

Comment: Edited as wished. However, you should know that you can edit your own questions yourself: look for the `edit` button just below your question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post can be useful, https://technpol.wordpress.com/2014/08/23/upgrading-to-ng-grid-3-0-ui-grid/

Basically, you need to set External scope for your grid, so that you can access data.

Comment: Thank helped a lot!  Got it working, but hit one weird snag and found a workaround.  I used a cellTemplate for one of the column fields and referenced an HTML file.  Worked fine.  When I tried the same for a cellHeader, hit errors.  What ended up working was taking the HTML and placing it in a var, the using the var reference in the column defs.  Worked fine.  Just found it to be really strange.